# CanvasJS - Striplines not displaying

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html5-canvas

I am trying to put together a chart for the FRED's Monthly Supply of Houses in the United States. I've been able to use Canvas.js to display the data but I can't seem to get strip-lines to work - I am trying to display a vertical strip-line for every recession but nothing shows up when I add the code and I'm following the Canvas.js documentation.

```
jQuery.getJSON("h/data/monthlySupplyHousesUS.json", function(results) {  
    $.each(results.dataset.data, function(key, value){
        twoPoints.push({x: new Date(value[0]), y: parseFloat(value[1])});
    });
    var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("monthlySupplyHousesUSChart",{
        title:{
            text:"Monthly Supply of Houses in United States"
        },
        axisX:{
            valueFormatString: "YYYY-MM",
            interval: 1,
            stripLines:[
                {
                    startValue:2007-01,
                    endValue:2009-01,                
                    color:"#d8d8d8",
                }
            ]                   
        },
        axisY: {
            title: "Supply"
        },
        toolTip: {
            shared: true
        },
        data: [{
            name: "Supply",
                showInLegend: true,
            legendText: "Index",
            type: "line",
            xValueFormatString: "YYYY-MM-DD",
            dataPoints : twoPoints
        }]
    });
    chart.render();
});
```

[image]

The JSON looks like:

```
{
  "dataset": {
    "id": 123643,
    "dataset_code": "MSACSR",
    "database_code": "FRED",
    "name": "Monthly Supply of Houses in the United States",
    "description": "Months' Supply Seasonally Adjusted, The months' supply is the ratio of houses for sale to houses sold. This statistic provides an indication of the size of the for sale inventory in relation to the number of houses currently being sold. The months' supply indicates how long  the current for sale inventory would last given the current sales rate if no additional new houses were built. ",
    "refreshed_at": "2018-06-25T23:28:04.022Z",
    "newest_available_date": "2018-05-01",
    "oldest_available_date": "1963-01-01",
    "column_names": ["Date", "Value"],
    "frequency": "monthly",
    "type": "Time Series",
    "premium": false,
    "limit": null,
    "transform": null,
    "column_index": null,
    "start_date": "1963-01-01",
    "end_date": "2018-05-01",
    "data": [
        ["2018-05-01", 5.2],
        ["2018-04-01", 5.5],
        ["2018-03-01", 5.3],
        ["2018-02-01", 5.4],
        ["2018-01-01", 5.6],
        ["2017-12-01", 5.5],
        ["2017-11-01", 4.9],
        ["2017-10-01", 5.6],
        ["2017-09-01", 5.3],
        ["2017-08-01", 6.0],
        ["2017-07-01", 6.0],
        ["2017-06-01", 5.3],
        ["2017-05-01", 5.4],
        ["2017-04-01", 5.4],
        ["2017-03-01", 5.0],
        ["2017-02-01", 5.1],
        ["2017-01-01", 5.3],
        ["2016-12-01", 5.6],
        ["2016-11-01", 5.3],
        ["2016-10-01", 5.2],
        ["2016-09-01", 5.2],
        ["2016-08-01", 5.0],
        ["2016-07-01", 4.5],
        ["2016-06-01", 5.2],
        ["2016-05-01", 5.2],
        ["2016-04-01", 5.1],
        ["2016-03-01", 5.4],
        ["2016-02-01", 5.4],
        ["2016-01-01", 5.5],
        ["2015-12-01", 5.2],
        ["2015-11-01", 5.5],
     ]
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the x-values are date-time, stripline values should also be given as date-time.

```
axisX:{
    valueFormatString: "YYYY-MM",
    interval: 1,
    stripLines:[
        {
            startValue: new Date("2007-01-01"),
            endValue:new Date("2009-01-01"),
            color:"#d8d8d8",
        }
    ]                   
},
```